# Slack Bolt SDK java Issue

Tags: slack, slack-api

Hi I am running Slack App which is written in the Bolt SDK For Java.

I am trying to do an OAuth By Bolt Java Code in Quarkus Framework . I am trying to call /slack/oauth/install as my redirect url where i can recieve the code . But however when i install the app its reporting that endpoint is not available (404)

Can someone help me why the endpoint is not visible and also tell me how to do OAuth Via Bolt SDK and then after getting access_token how can i redirect to my website log in page to connect the App .

```html
@WebServlet("/slack/oauth")
public class OAuthController extends SlackAppServlet {

    public OAuthController(){
        super(initiateOauth());
    }

    public OAuthController(App app){
        super(app);
    }

    private static App initiateOauth() {

        AppConfig appConfig = AppConfig.builder().clientId(CLIENT_ID)
                .clientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
                .scope(CLIENT_SCOPE)
                .oauthInstallPath("install")
                .oauthRedirectUriPath("oauth_redirect")
                .build();

        App oauth = new App(appConfig);
        oauth.asOAuthApp(true);

        oauth.endpoint(WebEndpoint.Method.GET, "slack/oauth/install", (request, context) -> Response.ok(request.getRequestBodyAsString()));

        return oauth;
    }
```